# What is the difference between passing constants as Props in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, input, components

While I was working with a `dx-calendar` component from DevExtreme, I face an issue.
I just wanted to pass 1 to `firstDayOfWeek` of that component in order to set Monday as the first day of the week.
So I tried:

```
<dx-calendar firstDayOfWeek="1" />
```

But it didn't work and the solution was:

```
<dx-calendar [firstDayOfWeek]="1" />
```

I thought they both are passing 1 to the component, but the behavior was different.

Related Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702062/how-to-fix-showing-the-days-of-week-incorrectly-in-dx-calendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the differences between them.
So the first one is passing a string "1" to the component and the second one was passing a number 1 to the component.

When we use [] for the attributes in Angular, the value is a kind of expression, and what's actually inputted to the component `eval("1")` that is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

This represents that you assign string value "1" to firstDayOfWeek prop.

```
<dx-calendar firstDayOfWeek="1" />
```

This represents that you assign int value 1 to firstDayOfWeek prop. ([] means assigning javascript value to `firstDayOfWeek`. So 1 is assigned as int value.)

```
<dx-calendar [firstDayOfWeek]="1" />
```